# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP MVC and utilizing the Intro to ASP MVC 4 Beta tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to find an answer to nor do I have much programming experience so I don't know where to even start to fix this an move on with the tutorial. I appreciate any help you can provide.

I'm in the Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller section and I am getting this error when I attempt to creat a Movie as a part of the tutorial, I click on the the link "Create New" and I get the following error

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page >"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts"

Rather than use Visual Studio express, I opted to download Visual Studio 2012 RC (not sure if that would be the root cause of my issue.

I realize you may require me to include code to answer this but I'm not sure what code to even include. Please advise what code you need me to include if any and I will be happy to add it to my question.

Thank you,

Comment: You should follow the Visual Studio 2012 version of that tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc-4-and-visual-studio-2011/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: i had the same issue and my problem was solved when i took RenderSection out of @{} and used only @. No idea why this happends

Comment: Link in RickAnd comment above does not work for me. But more importantly, this is not a tutorial issue, it's a VS code generation issue that is easily fixed and shouldn't be just papered over by removing the failing line as many answers below the accepted one suggest. See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27152625/165164) below for a discussion of what is really going on -- at least for some versions of VS.

Comment: The error stated is produced when a view has defined a `@section` which is NOT rendered in the Layout (with `RenderSection`). This can occur if you've referenced the wrong `Layout`, or forgotten to reference a layout at all. See [@vonv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15574224/314291)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

It means that you have defined a section in your master Layout.cshtml, but you have not included anything for that section in your View.

If your _Layout.cshtml has something like this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts")
```

Then all Views that use that Layout **must** include a `@section` with the same name (even if the contents of the section are empty):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section scripts{
    // Add something here
}
```

As an alternative, 
you can set required to false, then you won't be required to add the section in every View,

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

or also you can wrap the `@RenderSection` in an `if` block,

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("scripts"))
{
    RenderSection("scripts");
}
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful. I did not identify any @RenderSection("Scripts") within the _Layout.cshtml but I did notice in the views that were automatically created when creating my Movies controller for this tutorial, that those had     @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
} So i deleted those for the time being and everything is working for now.

Comment: while your answer is good. I think you should point out that adding `, required: false)` making it `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` will allow it to be included or not.

Comment: @KDark11 When creating a view VS asks if you want to reference the scripts. Just un-tick that.

Comment: I concur that putting `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` into the generated _Layout.cshtml is the right solution. (See discussion below for why.) That way you can add the fix in one file, not all -- a much DRYer fix.

Comment: @Eonasdan wow that's awesome! when did they add that feature? please don't tell me v1.0 :-/

Comment: I don't recall exactly, probably MVC 2 or 3.

Comment: The first line is the opposite of what the problem actually is. The error means that in the VIEW page, a section is defined, but in the layout page, that section is not being rendered.

Answer (score 30):

I had a case with 3 levels a'la _*MainLayout.cshtml* <--- _*Middle.cshtml* <--- *Page.cshtml*. Even though doing like this:

**_MainLayout.cshtml**

```
<head>
   @RenderSection("head", false)
</head>
```

**_Middle.cshtml**

```
@section head {
    @RenderSection("head")
}
```

and in **Page.cshtml** defining

```
@section head {
   ***content***
}
```

I would still get the error

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page “~/Views/Shared/_Middle.cshtml”: "head".

Turned out, the error was for the **Middle.cshtml** to rely on **/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml**
 to resolve it's parent layout. The problem was resolved by defining this in **Middle.cshtml** explicitly:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/_Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Can't decide whether this would be by-design or a bug in MVC 4 - anyhow, problem was solved :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The point is i'm calling RenderSection before RenderBody and inside Body Content i'm defining the section. Could it be?

Comment: Today I learned how to do "middle layout" thanks to code sample here. `@section Foo {@RenderSection("Foo")}` to "pass on" the sections! Also had to pass on the body with `@RenderBody()`.

Comment: very clever :)))

Answer (score 28):

Also, you can add the following line to the `_Layout.cshtml` or `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml`:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure why the accepted answer was accepted if the suggested solution did not and does not solve the issue. There can actually be two related issues related to this topic.

**Issue #1**

The master page (e.g. `_Layout.cshtml`) has a section defined and it is **required** but the inheriting views did not implement it. For example,

**The Layout Template**

```
<body>
    @* Visible only to admin users *@
    <div id="option_box"> 
        @* this section is required due to the absence of the second parameter *@
        @RenderSection("OptionBox") 
    </div>
</body>
```

**The Inheriting View**

No need to show any code, just consider that there is **no** implementation of `@section OptionBox {}` on the view.

**The Error for Issue #1**

`Section not defined: "OptionBox ".`

**Issue #2**

The master page (e.g. `_Layout.cshtml`) has a section defined and it is **required AND** the inheriting view **did** implement it. However, the implementing view have additional `script` sections that **are not defined** on (any of) its master page(s).

**The Layout Template**

`same as above`

**The Inheriting View**

```
<div>
  <p>Looks like the Lakers can still make it to the playoffs</p>
</div>
@section OptionBox {
<a href"">Go and reserve playoff tickets now</a>
}
@section StatsBox {
<ul>
    <li>1. San Antonio</li>
    <li>8. L. A. Lakers</li>
</ul>
}
```

**The Error for Issue #2**

`The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "StatsBox"`

The OP's issue is similar to Issue #2 and the accepted answer is for Issue #1.

Comment: Agreed, OP's comment is he deleted a section in view to resolve the error, which means he had a section defined in a view, but not in layout, not the other way around as most of the answers address(Issue #2 which corresponds to the error they describe)  All the other answers are describing a situation that wouldn't produce that error, but instead "Section not defined" rather than "sections have been defined but... not rendered".

Answer (score 10):

I think our solution was sufficiently different from everyone elses so I'll document it here.

We have setup of Main layout, an intermediary layout and then the final action page render. Main.cshtml <- Config.cshtml <- Action.cshtml

Only when web.config had `customErrors='On/RemoteOnly'` we got a custom error and no exception nor `Application_Error` was called. I could catch this on `Layout = null` line in the Error.cshtml. Exception was as in the question, missing scripts section.

We did have it defined in Main.cshtml (with required:false) and Action.cshtml didn't have anything that wrote into the scripts section.

Solution was to add `@section scripts { @RenderSection("scripts", false) }` to Config.cshtml.

Answer (score 10):

It appears that there is a mismatch between the View files that some versions of Visual Studio auto-generates for you when you use it to create a new Model. I encountered this problem using the [new VS 2013 Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) and walking through the W3Schools tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_app.asp but the comments above indicate that its not a problem with the tutorial directions or with a single version of VS.

It is true that you can make the error message **go away** by just removing the

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

line from the create/edit layouts that were autogenerated by Visual Studio.

But that solution does not address the root cause or leave you in a good place to do more than finish walking through the tutorial. At some point (probably fairly early) in the development of a real application, you are going to want access to the jquery validation code that the commenting-out solution removes from your app.

If you use VS to create a new model for you, it also creates a set of five View files: Create, Delete, Details, Edit, and Index. Two of these views, Create and Edit are intended to let the user add/edit data for the fields in database records that underlie the model. For those views in a real app, you will probably want to do some amount of data validation using the jquery validation library before you save the record in the db. That is why VS adds the following lines

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

to the bottom of those two views and not others. The autogenerated code is trying to make the validation library available for those views, but not the others.

The error happens because VS either doesn't add a corresponding line to the shared _Layout.cshtml file or, see one answer above, adds it but leaves it commented out. This line is

`@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

If some of your views have a scripts section (as Create and Edit do), there has to be a RenderSection command embedded in the layout. If some scripts have the section and some do not (as Delete, Details, and Index do not), the RenderSection command has to have the `required: false` parameter.

So the best solution, if you want to do anything more than just finish walking through the tutorial, is to add the statement to _Layout.cshtml not remove the code from the Edit and Create views.

P.S. It is a bit of a confuser, here, that what is being required is in a 'bundle' and the require statement looks like it is trying to include a file in a bundles folder that does not exist in your project. But, for debug builds and tutorials, that's not relevant since the bundled files get included one at a time. See: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification The code that is at issue here is mentioned briefly about two-thirds of the way down the page.

Comment: This "rocks" and is a really good explanation.  Perhaps it came in later so didn't get many votes....

Answer (score 8):

It occurs basically when **_Layout.cshtml** is without:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

or with

```
@RenderSection("scripts")
```

WITHOUT

```
required: false
```

So, Just add
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
in **_Layout.cshtml** 
and it works specially for those developers who works with **Kendoui** genarated projects.

Answer (score 4):

I just got that error and I read that the reason behind is you must render a script section. But in _Layout it was already as is.

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Also it worked before I added the section at the bottom of the page.

The reason in my case was a simple typo in spelling `Scripts`.

```
@section Scripts{
<script src="~/js/myScript.js"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While working through the ASP.NET MVC 4 Tutorial with Visual Studio 2012 I encountered the same error in the "Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller section". The fix is quite simple.

When creating a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application in Visual Studio 2012 within the _Layout.cshtml document in the shared folder the "scripts" section is commented out.

```
    @*@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)*@
```

Simply un-comment the line and the sample code should work.

```
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue while implementing a tutorial for beginners of MVC. I got various suggestion to modify the @RenderSection in your layout.cshtml file but I havn't use it.

I have search a lot and then I found that the script tag generated in a (View/Edit.cshtml) and other cshtml file is not rendering

```
**@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

}**

So I removed those lines and application start running smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the "_Layout.cshtml" like below and it works.
.Net Core 3.1 Blazor Server module Identity issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)


</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content px-4">


            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


@section Scripts {    
    
}
```

Comment: Also other solution is https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1325#issuecomment-641800267 I used it when I have updated Identity Register page and it shows jquery error.

Comment: Adding @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you are rendering your section from within an @section in the _Layout file that is referring to a partial view with an @section, i.e. you've nested an @section within an @section. In the _Layout file, remove the @section around the rendersection.

Answer (score 1):

I have also commented **@section Scripts 
than it's running smoothly. :)

Answer (score 1):

for me it was that i said ***script*** instead of ***scripts***
i dont know why it doesn't show me as an error while debuging it.

`@section Script {}`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30266217)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the error in the web and came to this page. 
I am using Visual Studio 2015 and this is my first MVC project.

If you miss the @ symbol before the render section you will get the same error. I would like to share this for future beginners.

```
 @RenderSection("headscripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

check the speling and Upper/Lower case of term ""

when ever we write 
    @RenderSection("name", required: false)
make sure that the razor view Contains a section
   @section name{}
so 
check the speling and Upper/Lower case of term ""
Correct in this case is "Scripts"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have typed correct spelling of using script section in view

the correct is

```
@section scripts{ //your script here}
```

if you typed `@section script{ //your script here}` this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the following,

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in my _Layout.cshtml I have RenderSection inside a condition

```
 @if (theme == "Red" || theme == "Green")
  {
       <div>
       @RenderSection("Footer", false)
       </div>
   }
```

and in my child view it was without condition

```
@section Footer{
        <div>
            @Html.AwButton("Reject", "Reject")
            @Html.AwSubmit("Ok", "Ok")
        </div>
    }
```

so irrespective of the theme, child was adding the Footer. But in parent when theme is not Red or Green it was not adding the Footer and unhanded exception being thrown.