# Server Error in '/' Application. Asp.net Mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hello I am starting to learn in web programming language using `asp.net mvc4` and `bootstrap`. I am getting this error `(Server Error in '/' Application)` when running my application but if it is in default code it is functioning fine.

These are my codes

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

*I didn't change anything here*

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="Corinthians 3" />

        <title>Sample BS</title>
   <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Animation CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/plugin/css/animate.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/plugin/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="../../plugin/dateTimePicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <label for="disabledSelect" style="color:#A94442; display:none;" id="lblTotalCollectibles"></label>
    </div>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0; background-color:#337AB7;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    < span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation < /span >
                    < span class="icon-bar">< /span >
                    < span class="icon-bar">< /span >
                    < span class="icon-bar">< /span >
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Content("~/BS/BSSSS")" style="color:White;">BS</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li style="margin-top:13px;">
                    <span class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:White;" id="timeTxt"></span>
                </li>  
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">                        
                        <li>

                        </li>  
                        <li> <!--style="display:none;"> -->

                        </li> 
                        <li> <!--style="display:none;"> -->

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw" id="side-menu-filemaintenance"></i> File Maintenance <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                <li>

                                </li>
                                <li>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                        </li>                  
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" style="background-image:url(../../Images/bg.gif); background-attachment: fixed;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/plugin/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/plugin/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    <script src="../../plugin/dateTimePicker/js/moment-with-locales.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../plugin/dateTimePicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/plugin/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/userdefined/Sales/jsSales.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And Lastly for my View>BS>BSSSS.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h1>aaaa</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KtyZ.png) of the error.

**UPDATED**

@Gaurav here is the new error that i follow your suggested way.

[image: NEW]

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971149/the-following-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-for-the-layo

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal wait2 i start to read it.

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal we have same error but the suggested answer said `@RenderSection("scripts")` but I don't have that kind of code.

Comment: I created new project and copied the same code, it worked, without any glitch.

You don't have any `@RenderSection("featured", required: false)`, in your layout page, so this error should not be raised.

Comment: I guess, some other action is called, kindly check some Index action.. like Home/Index. Because your image shows that clearly you are not calling `BS/BSSSS` i.e. controller `BS` and action `BSSSS`

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal yes i don't have that code and i don't know what is happening to my new project. I try to add `<div class="container-fluid">
                @RenderBody() @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            </div>` but the source of view is getting in different path of folder.

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal can you make a chat discussion?. It is already said to avoid extended discussion in comments.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45624/gj-kira

Comment: I can't enter any word.. why?

Comment: You need 20 reputation. Ignore all, just check the action which is called first.

Comment: if i use the RenderSection the action is getting from the Home>Index.. But I want it from BS>BSS(or any view)

Comment: I can do that.. But how can I do like BS(folder)>BSS(view)?

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal wait i am still working on it.

Comment: Yes i Created a folder name `BS`

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal Please post your answer to configure the route i will accept it.. It is okay now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

Rename your `BSSSS.cshtml` to `Index.cshtml` and move it to `Views/Home` folder *(replace existing file)*. 
Leave the statement as `return View();` in `Home` controller's `Index`action.

**Approach 2**

Let the `BSSSS.cshtml` file remain at path `Views/BS/BSSSS.cshtml`. In your `Home` controller's `Index` action change the `return View();` to `return View("BSS/BSSSS.cshtml");`