# System.Web.HttpException when using [Authorize]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-authorization

I am facing a very weird problem that I am unable to solve.
I have this button onclick of which I go to the controller action method where I need to use [Authorize], when I use [Authorize] I get the following error.

The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".

[System.Web.HttpException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcQPC.png)

However, when I don't use [Authorize] it works fine. Why does it behave like that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Calendar(int id, string start, string end)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971149/the-following-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-for-the-layo. Probably the layout doesn't have non-required section.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the exception only comes when I put [Authorize] tag on my ActionMethod , otherwise it works fine. I tried making the non-req section false, but it didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` page you have likely a required section that has to be included on every view, it will be something like this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts")
```

You need to change it to this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Which means the section will be optional on pages using your layout page.

Old but still relevant:

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor

Comment: my _Layout.cshtml does not have @RenderSection("scripts"). I tried adding @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) but the exception was still there. the thing is it works fine when i remove [authorize] tag.

Comment: When you add the authorize attribute if you are not currently authenticated it will be redirecting you to your login view which will be where the required section is not implemented, whereas if you remove the attribute it will just be displaying the Calendar view. I suggest you post the _layout.cshtml and login view HTML.

Comment: oh i see. actually i am using this [Authorize] on the action method with has the outlook auth api.. which i am using for fetching auth token for outlook login and then adding my event to the outlook calendar.

Comment: Do you know what view is actually throwing the error? I'm pretty confident the problem is going to be per my answer above, you just need to work out with your auth mechanism where the user is ending up and the view that's causing the issue. Do you know that your auth mechanism is working?

Comment: yes you were right, there was some problem with my auth mechanism. fixed it. works fine now. thanks a lot. much appreciated!