# MVC error Scripts not rendered for the layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application which was working fine.  I made a few minor changes in one of the controllers and now I get the following error:  The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".  The error is from the login page that had the following razor:

```
section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}
```

(the error goes away if comment this out).
I have the following bundle in my bundlesConfig file, (and is 'hit' when I debug the application and is listed as one of the bundles when I inspect the bundles in the watch window).

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"));
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting his problem as it was working and I haven't made any conscious changes to the login page or the bundlesConfig.
(The global.asax file includes the line    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971149/the-following-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-for-the-layout-page-views-shared-layout-cshtml-scripts hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you manthan.  I did see that post before I submitted the question and it didn't help.   I finally found a solution from this post:  [link][1]

I added to my _Layout.cshtml page after the renderbody another line.

```
 <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
 </div>
```

When I added the @Scripts.Render() to the individual pages, it was looking for the @RenderSection in the layout page.  What I still don't understand is how this worked for 4 years without this line?