# Full identity scaffolding fails because of Razor script tag

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, asp.net5

I scaffolded all the Razor views, because I want to edit them.

However some of them have this at the bottom:

```
@section Scripts {
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

This is the error that I get:

> InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").

Note that I do want those scripts to be rendered. Why does it crash? How to best resolve it?

Comment: Sounds like your layout page is missing a Scripts section. You can remove those from the page if you don't need them.

Comment: Can you share your _layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971149/the-following-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-for-the-layo).

> It means that you have defined a section in your master Layout.cshtml, but you have not included anything for that section in your View.

In your `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml`,it should include the code:

```
@section Scripts 
{
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```